# Area of triangle constructed from the medians of other triangle

Tags: triangles, median

We have triangle ABC of area P. Is it possible to compute the area of a triangle with sides "made" from medians of the triangle ABC in terms of P I'm looking for some hints maybe,

Comment: Where did you see this question?  Just to know whether there Is a definite answer

Comment: It't the exact formulation of the problem in my textbook.

Comment: Hint:  If $A,B,C$ are the vertices and $a,b,c$ the opposite sides, extend the median from $A$ through $a$ and intersect it with the line through $B$ parallel to the median out of $C$.  You should find a triangle similar to the median triangle.  [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/MedianTriangle.shtml) is a useful discussion.